# Does confluent cloud audit events for connectors?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

Is there any way to log audit events for Kafka connectors (created from confluent UI). I can see all the default events logged by confluent at this url: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/audit-logs/auditable-events.html#auditable-events

Connectors is not present in the list, is there any way to enable audit logs for connectors?